# General form of a sequence of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series

I obtained the following as **parts** of solutions of this integration  ${\displaystyle \int^{r}\frac{\sin k\left[2 \arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{-x^{2}-1}}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{-r^{2}-1}}\right)+y\right]}{x\sqrt{x^{2}+1}} dx}$, for k=1, 2, ..... Obviously there is a relation relating the solutions but the general formula is proving abortive. Any help or suggestion will be duly appreciated.

- $u_{1} = \frac{1}{x}$
- $u_{2} = \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}{x^{2}}$
- $u_{3} = \frac{3x^{2}+4}{3x^{3}}$
- $u_{4} = \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}(x^{2}+2)}{x^{4}}$
- $u_{5} = \frac{5x^{4}+20x^{2}+16}{5x^{5}}$
- $u_{6} = \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}(x^{2}+4)(3x^{2}+4)}{3x^{6}}$
- $u_{7} = \frac{7x^{6}+56x^{4}+112x^{2}+64}{7x^{7}}$
- $u_{8} = \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}(x^{2}+2)(x^{4}+8x^{2}+8)}{x^{8}}$
- $u_{9} = \frac{(3x^{2}+4)(3x^{6}+36x^{4}+96x^{2}+64)}{9x^{9}}$
- $u_{10} = \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}(x^{4}+12x^{2}+16)(5x^{4}+20x^{2}+16)}{5x^{10}}$
- $u_{11} = \frac{11x^{10}+220x^{8}+1232x^{6}+2816x^{4}+2816x^{2}+1024}{11x^{11}}$
- $u_{12} = \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}(x^{2}+4)(3x^{2}+4)(x^{2}+2)(x^{4}+16x^{2}+16)}{3x^{12}}$
- ...
- $u_{k} = ???$

Comment: What is the function?

Comment: I have updated the question